# dijit.byId("").is not defined in Worklight works with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I make a project in worklight used dojo mobile 1.8.1 and angularjs 1.0.1,but i got a strange problem.

Here is my html part:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" data-dojo-props="selected:true"  id="id1" ></div>

<div class="full" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="id2"></div>
```

and my JavaScript part:

```
require([
"dojo", "dijit/_base/manager","dojo/parser", "dijit/registry",
], function(dojo) {
dojo.ready(function() {

// dijit.byId("id1").performTransition("id2");   //////////place I

});
});


var angularApp = angular.module('app', [])
.run(['$rootScope','$templateCache','$route',
  function($rootScope,$templateCache,$route) {

dijit.byId("id1").performTransition("id2");////////place II
}]);
```

The problem is at place I, it works well, but when I put "dijit.byId("id1")" at place II, it shows:

> dijit.byId("").is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ready function is executed after dojo parsed your document & constructed the widgets you try to get using dijit.byId.

The second part is not placed within the ready function, so dojo can't find your elements yet !

**Solution:** Access your elements in the ready function **OR** do not declare them declaratively (like you did, using html code...) !

Lucian

Comment: thank you for your infomation,but can you give me a example about : "do not declare them declaratively (like you did, using html code...)"  ，i want to do something in the second part.thanks

Comment: You should take a look at some dojo tutorials on how to create widgets declaratively or programmatically, take a look here:

http://davidwalsh.name/dojo-widget

Comment: if you want to do something in the second part, why dont you put the ready function around the second part too ? then it should work

Comment: thank you ,it works, i'm a beginner,and i will learn the tutorials you gave me ,thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The dojo.ready() function registers an event-handler function (callback) which will be fired after the DOM got completely parsed. 
This comes in very handy if you want to be sure that every html element got rerendered as dojo-widget before you perform operations on them.

So, in your example, Code II will be executed before the dijit.byId() function has been made available by loading the necessary modules (dijit/registry, ...). Code II would only work after the dom-ready event got fired and your "dojo.ready()" function did load the required modules.

You should definately invest 5 minutes in reading what dojo.ready() is about:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/ready.html

Sidenote:
You shouldn't use dijit.byId() any more in Dojo 1.8.1. Try using dijit.registry.byId() (you have to require the dijit/registry module).

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/registry.html#dijit-registry-byid